# Expo - How to create database connection to GraphQL on Android device via httpLink

Tags: android, react-native, graphql, expo

I have issues getting my app working properly on my `Android` device. What I try is a connection to database via `apollo` and `httpLink` to `GraphQL`.

On the `expo web` it works perfectly. Clicking the search button correctly creates a connection to the database.

I have created an example to better demonstrate it to you.

**Web:**

[image: web]

But now deploying the same code with `expo android` on my Android device and the button isn't working anymore, without showing any error in the logs. But when I for testing purpose set an `alert()` on the button it shows the alert correctly. So the functionality of the button is fine, it is just failing on the connecting to the database. I also checked the logs of my device but was not able to find any error somehow.

**Android:**

[image: android]

This is wierd because this one:

```
httpLink = createHttpLink({
  ...
})
```

works perfectly fine with any of these:

```
uri: 'http://192.168.178.24:4000'
uri: 'http://localhost:4000'
```

[image: expo view]

So my question is how to fix that database connection issue with my `Android` device. I'm pretty sure it is just the issue of the `uri` and nothing else as the web version is working properly.

Maybe the last hint, when I open `http://192.168.178.24:4000` in a regular browser on my Android device I get the `GraphQL` backend. So the device is able to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the reason was not the `uri` or any connection issue.

First I tested what happens when I try to set dummy data:

```
const links = [
  {
    "id": "ck8vbt27p0031074531nvryg0",
    "url": "www.google.de",
    "description": "search engine",
  }
]
this.setState({ links })
```

This was a good choice because it was working on my Android device.

But susing real data from database was not working.

That's why I switch from using the `async await`, to the following:

```
const SearchScreen = () => {
  let [filter] = useState(null);
  const [getLinks, { loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(FEED_SEARCH_QUERY);

  if (loading) return <Text>Loading ...</Text>;

  if (data){
    ...
  }
```

And now it works also on Android. So there is some issue on Android when using async await. As the [official queries](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2.6/data/queries/#executing-queries-manually) docs page tell using the `useLazyQuery`, that is pretty much an issue of the specific Apollo version. So in newer version it's more properly working without the `await`.